# Unable to verify a call to a method on the mocked object with multiple interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to write unit test for `TranslateResponse()`.

```
private async Task TranslateResponse(Policy policy)
{
  foreach(t in translatorFactory.BuildTranslator())
  {
    var policyTranslator=t as IPolicyAwareTranslator;
    policyTranslator?.SetPolicy(policy);
  }
}
```

The `TranslateResponse()` has many other translators though, but for now, I limited it to just one.
The `BuildTranslator` is as

```
public async Task<List<ITranslator>> BuildTranslators()
{
   return new List<ITranslator>()
   {
     new PolicyTranslator()
   }
}
```

Here I'm returning the `PolicyTranslator` which implements `ITranslator` and `IPolicyAwareTranslator`

`ITranslator` has `Translate()` while `IPolicyAwareTranslator` has `SetPolicy(Policy policy)` respectively.
Now that for Unit testing, I create a Mock of `ITranslator` and set it up and I create the Mock of `IPolicyTranslator` via As<>.

```
Mock<ITranslator> mockedTranslator=new Mock<ITranslator>();
mockedTranslator.Setup(t => t.Translate(_translatorDataAccessor.Object));

var mockedPolicyTranslator = mockedTranslator.As<IPolicyAwareTranslator>();
mockedPolicyTranslator.Setup(t => t.SetPolicy(It.IsAny<Policy>()));

List<ITranslator> translators = new List<ITranslator>(new List<ITranslator>() { mockedTranslator.Object });
translatorFactory.Setup(t => t.BuildTranslators(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(translators);
```

Still the verify call fails.
I'm I going in the right direction or missing something?

```
mockedPolicyTranslator.Verify(t => t.SetPolicy(new UnknownPolicy()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument matcher will need to be loosened

```
mockedPolicyTranslator.Verify(t => t.SetPolicy(It.IsAny<UnknownPolicy>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

since currently used `new UnknownPolicy()` instance wont match whatever is passed while testing